# How to replace sharepoint group users with new users?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

> This is I'm upto

```
var clientContextForGroup = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var siteGroups = clientContextForGroup.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    var web = clientContextForGroup.get_web();
    spGroup = siteGroups.getByName(GroupName);

    var userCollection = spGroup.get_users();

    $.each(MembersArray, function (index, tempitem) {
        var userCreationInfo = new SP.UserCreationInformation();
        userCreationInfo.set_email(tempitem.EMail);
        userCreationInfo.set_loginName(tempitem.Name);
        userCreationInfo.set_title(tempitem.Title);
        userCollection.add(userCreationInfo);
    });

    clientContextForGroup.load(userCollection);
    clientContextForGroup.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        console.log("added in SPGroup");
    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.log("Sorry Some Error occurred in adding user in SPGroup...");
    });
```

> this adds new member if any in 'MembersArray'.
>   I want to replace all members with new members.

Answer (score 0):

You could call [removeByLoginName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245315.aspx)  to remove a user if user doesn't exist in MembersArray.

Sample code from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123448/how-to-remove-user-from-sharepoint-group-using-javascript).

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oWeb = clientContext.get_web()
var collGroup = oWeb.get_siteGroups();
var oGroup = collGroup.getById(7); //Change 7 based on the group's id
var oUser = oGroup.get_users();
clientContext.load(oUser);
var user = web.ensureUser("domain\username);
oUser.removeByLoginName(user.get_loginName());   

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));

function onQuerySucceeded(){
    alert('User Removed');
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    alert('Failed');
}
```

Comment: But for this, first I have to get users from group. Then check for common users.... other than this can I use oUser.update() like this?

Comment: Check the api https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245943.aspx, the users property of SP.Group support Get only.